# How to use CSS template in my ASP.net web site

Tags: asp.net

Hiii
I am using asp.net visual studio-2010 framework 3.5 on win 7. I have download readymade template designed made in css.I copied index.html code and paste it in masterpage and also copy the code of div content and paste it in content place holder.It's working. I want to add another page like about.html,sevice.html, etc.Plzz  help me what the procedure to add another page
thank you.....

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Add New Item->Webform & check the select master page checkbox to select your exisiting master page.

Comment: thanks
I did it....after open the another page like about.html What will do? and Which code copy to master page of another page please explain....

Comment: Just keep adding your new pages & don't forget to select the master page you created. There is no need of copying the code.